# Javascript get value from a json using varible as a key

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, frontend

This is the json response which i receive (consider that it is in a proper json format)
for json in proper format pls see here https://jsonblob.com/57c6d993e4b0dc55a4f1fcd6

```
i am using an ajax call to get the response, i want to get the id and product
```

i can get the value when i use something like this

```
alert(response.issue.backingMap.india.camera[0].product);
```

and it is printing properly as **"ghee"**
but in my case, india and camera are actually stored in a variable consider it to be country and type respectively 
**eg var country = india** and **var type=camera**.

`alert(response.issue.backingMap.country.type[0].product);` is not working. how can i use a variable here

Comment: `backingMap[country][type][0]`

Answer (score 1):

you should use the following format than

```
response.issue.backingMap[country][type][0].product
```

where country and type are variables with the right value.